# How to select certain text between other text in python?

Tags: python, split, findall

Here is an example string:

`text = "hello, i like to eat beef 'sandwiches' and beef 'jerky' and chicken 'patties' and chicken 'burgers' and also chicken 'fingers' and other chicken 'meat' too."`

I am trying to separate the words "patties", "burgers", 
fingers", and "meat" from this text. I want to separate the words after chicken but before the closing quotation.

I have gotten stumped on how to even separate a single one. I can split after `"chicken '` but then how can i select the text up until the next `'` ?

I would like to iterate through a list to save the variables to an array. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Please add your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re

text = "hello, i like to eat beef 'sandwiches' and beef 'jerky' and chicken 'patties' and chicken 'burgers' and also chicken 'fingers' and other chicken 'meat' too."

match = re.findall(r'chicken \'(\S+)\'', text)
print (match)
```

Outputs:

```
['patties', 'burgers', 'fingers', 'meat']
```

Comment: Regex was my first thought as well, it looks like you beat me to it. That's a nice solution.

Comment: Just what i was stock on. i was trying regular expressions, but was stumped on exactly how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions can be daunting at first, but the good news is there are plenty of resources out there. [This](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/regular-expressions) is a free course on regex I can recommend (it uses javascript though).

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use-case for regex.

```
import re
print(re.findall(r"chicken '(.*?)'", text))
```

Here's an explanation of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/8IdseD/1

Here's the python code running: https://repl.it/repls/SquareQuerulousModes

The regex, part by part:

- `chicken '` - matches that literal text
- `(` - starts a capture group - the part that `re.findall` will spit out.
- `.` - matches any character...
- `*?` - ...any number of times, but as few possible (this is to ensure we don't capture the final `'`)
- `)` - end the capture group
- `'` - match a literal `'`.

So `re.findall` will give you a list of all the substrings that are captured in the group.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zero-width lookarounds to match the surroundings:

```
(?<=chicken\s')[^']+(?=')
```

- `(?<=chicken\s')` is zero-width positive lookbehind that matches `chicken '`
- `[^']+` matches the portion upto next single quote i.e. the desired substring
- `(?=')` is zero-width positive lookahead that matches `'` after the desired substring

**Example:**

```
In [713]: text = "hello, i like to eat beef 'sandwiches' and beef 'jerky' and chicken 'patties' and chicken 'burgers' and also chicken 'fingers' and other chicken 'meat' too."                             

In [714]: re.findall(r"(?<=chicken\s')[^']+(?=')", text)                                                                                                                                                    
Out[714]: ['patties', 'burgers', 'fingers', 'meat']
```

Answer (score 0):

Select just the portion of the sentence from the first occurrence of "chicken":

```
chicken_text = text[text.find("chicken"):]
```

Split that text on spaces:

```
chicken_words = chicken_text.split(" ")
```

Scan the list for words that begin and end with a single quote:

```
for word in chicken_words:
    if word[0] == "'" and word[-1] == "'":
        print word[1:-1]
```

This won't work if the single-quoted words themselves contain spaces, but that isn't the case in the sample text you gave.

Comment: You're missing the parentheses in the last line, `print word[1:-1]` should be `print (word[1:-1])`

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla This question wasn't tagged python3.

Comment: You're right, my bad! I'm used to using python3 so using print without parentheses just looked wrong to me. Sorry!